# Concat column name in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is there a way to concat a column name as t26.`crea`+`ted_at`?

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.user, t26.`crea`+`ted_at` FROM users t0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_logs t26 ON (t0.id = t26.aid)
WHERE ((t26.`crea`+`ted_at` >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND (t26.`crea`+`ted_at` <= '2019-01-31 23:59:59'));
```

I simply need to fetch data from a certain date but a system is filtering the created_at column because it contains the keyword `create`

Comment: This is not standard SQL and very few databases have functionality even remotely similar to this.  You can, however, use dynamic SQL (that is, construct the query as a string).

Comment: When asking SQL questions, you should always tell us the DBMS you are using (i.e. tag the request with the DBMS).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, sorry, edited, it's MariaDB

Comment: What system lets you write SQL, but filters out keywords? I think that should be done by administrating privileges

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate some column , it becomes string and you can't use SQL operator (>=, <=, >, <) to compare string value.

But you can try this to fetch your data between two date:

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.user, t26.`crea` `ted_at` 
FROM users t0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_logs t26 ON (t0.id = t26.aid)
WHERE (     
            (t26.`crea` >= '2018-01-01' AND ted_at >= '00:00:00') 
            AND 
            (t26.`crea` <= '2019-01-31' AND ted_at <= '23:59:59') 
      )
```

Comment: You didnt understand the question! No, he does not have a column crea and a column ted_at. Apparently mariadb lets you seperate column names

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.user, concat(t26.crea,ted_at) FROM users t0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_logs t26 ON (t0.id = t26.aid)
WHERE ((concat(t26.crea,ted_at) >= '2018-01-01 00:00:00') AND (concat(t26.crea,ted_at) <= 
'2019-01-31 23:59:59'));
```

You can also use between clause,

```
SELECT t0.id, t0.user, concat(t26.crea,ted_at) FROM users t0
RIGHT OUTER JOIN user_logs t26 ON (t0.id = t26.aid)
WHERE concat(t26.crea,ted_at) between '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-01-31 
23:59:59';
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all, even tried adding quotes as `concat('t26.crea','ted_at')`. :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to construct a query.  But you must do it inside a Stored Routine.  See the use of `PREPARE` (with a `CONCAT` like you have), `EXECUTE`, and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.